# ESLint configuration and peer dependencies

Tags: config, eslint

It's considered a good practice to add all plugins/parsers of a custom eslint config as peer deps. The reasoning behind it is something about having multiple versions of the same package. My question is: Is there a (sane) way to avoid this? I tried publishing my own configs before where everything is in deps, and had no issue with that. Babel configs are shared without having to peer install every used plugin. Why ESLint is different?

Comment: Currently there are 3 way to work around this:
https://github.com/eslint/eslint/pull/12460#issuecomment-549108202 (also a PR to fix it)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the 4 workarounds listed by @Arvigeus, there are two others I found, which I prefer:

1. Using the [resolve-plugins-relative-to](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface#--resolve-plugins-relative-to) ESLint option. For the VSCode extension, you can set this using `"eslint.options.resolvePluginsRelativeTo": "..."` in `.vscode/settings.json`.
2. Import the [eslint-patch](https://github.com/microsoft/rushstack/tree/master/stack/eslint-patch) patching-script at the start of your `.eslintrc.js` file.

It's frustrating that eslint's [proposal to improve config dependencies](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/13481) is not completed yet, but the two workarounds above are better than nothing.